Can I restrict which users can `sendmail` from an address with Postfix?
I've set up Postfix on my server (let's call it example.com), and I can prevent SMTP clients that don't authenticate as admin from sending email from admin@example.com with (for example):
# main.cf
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/smtpd_sender_login_map
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_known_sender_login_mismatch

# /etc/postfix/smtpd_sender_login_map
admin admin

However, an unprivileged user mallory who can run programs on my server can still send email from admin@example.com by running the sendmail program:
mallory@server$ sendmail -f admin@example.com -t < spam.txt
# Postfix allows the email to be sent

I'd like to keep sendmail enabled on my server if possible, because it's convenient to let programs like dnf-automatic and fail2ban to use it to send email to me. I've searched both postfix.org and the internet for ways to restrict the behavior of sendmail, but everything I've found has been about SMTP. Is it possible to restrict which users can sendmail from a specific address with Postfix?

PS: See the comments under this answer for a discussion on why you may not want this setup.

As already answered not easily.
If you can't trust your users to behave themselves and to not abuse the privilege of access to the postfix sendmail compatibility interface ( /usr/lib/sendmail and/or /usr/sbin/sendmail)  either via the command line or trough their (web) applications, then don't allow them access at all. Mandate that they always submit their messages over SMTP, with authentication, where it is much easier to restrict messages to use a From: address that matches with the credentials used to submit the message.  That also makes it much easier to identify abuse and to stop it, as you can simply block the specific compromised/abusive account.
Postfix provides  the authorized_submit_users directive to set an explicit list of trusted (system) users that are allowed to use sendmail command and/or native postdrop commands and/or list specific users that aren't.

That is a valid point and probably the very reason why there aren't any out-of-the-box solutions for this. With Sendmail, as the uid is logged in the logs & the headers, it is easy to spot users abusing their privileges and block their shell access altogether.

That uid did not help nearly as much as you would hope with the canonical problem which was of course  mod_php and the php mail() function which uses the sendmail command. Try to identify which website has the compromised mail form when your logs only contain the uid of the webserver and you host 100’s of sites on a single shared web server.

Furthermore, if you grant your users shell access, you typically grant them access to send email on behalf of the server, bypassing Postfix altogether. They could simply use any binary like nc smtp.google.com 25 to send email.

Regarding PHP, I would not use mod_php on a multisite server anyway. With per site users and per user FPM pools it is not only possible to know which site sent the message but also to delimit a compromise to the single site. If there is, e.g., a path traversal vulnerability or someone manages to install a web shell, an attacker gets access to all the files the site has access to, and they typically contain database credentials that can be used to steal more data. Using mod_php is simply against the principle of least privilege.

There is one scenario where it might be better to be able to control the Sendmail regardless of the direct access to the Internet. That is when there is DKIM+DMARC involved, because it will not only allow send mail but to send authenticated mail. However, that would also require other controls like not including the server to the SPF policy of the example.com and using an envelope sender that does not align in DMARC. Then, it would already be better to have a separate mail infrastructure and block outbound 25 from the shell server...  +1 to your answer because it keeps things simple.

Postfix >= 3.6 has the local_login_sender_maps option which can be used to restrict the “envelope from” addresses specified by local users:
local_login_sender_maps (default: static:*)
       A  list  of lookup tables that are searched by the UNIX login name, and
       that return a list of allowed envelope  sender  patterns  separated  by
       space or comma. These sender patterns are enforced by the Postfix post‐
       drop(1) command. The default is backwards-compatible:  every  user  may
       specify any sender envelope address.


Note that this map works in a reverse way from smtpd_sender_login_maps — instead of returning the list of login names which are authorized to use the specified envelope sender address, it needs to return the list of envelope sender addresses which can be used by the specified login name.
With PCRE maps you can do things like restricting your users to use only the address where the local part matches the login name:
# Allow both the bare username and the user@domain forms.
/(.+)/ $1 $1@example.com

(or maybe use /^([^:]+)$/ to avoid matching the uid:12345 keys which can appear when Postfix can't map the UID to the UNIX login name).

Nice! Postfix is ​​constantly evolving, and sometimes new features fall off my radar. This should be the accepted answer. +1

For Postfix < 3.6 that had no local_login_sender_maps
As Sergey Vlasov noticed in his answer, this has become possible in Postfix >= 3.6.
For Postfix < 3.6, I am afraid there is no configuration parameter for what you want, but knowing how the mail flows in Postfix, i.e., the Postfix Architecture, helps to understand where you could sort things out. This answer does not have a complete, working solution, but the building blocks you can use.
TL;DR: It is not easy and requires scripting skills, but it is doable.
How Postfix receives mail

                             trivial-
                             rewrite(8)
Network  --->  smtpd(8)         ^ |
                       \        | v
Network  --->  qmqpd(8) ---> cleanup(8)  --> incoming
                       /
              pickup(8) <--- maildrop
                                ^
                                |
Local  ---> sendmail(1) ---> postdrop(1)


Local submissions are received with the Postfix sendmail(1) compatibility command, and are queued in the maildrop queue by the privileged postdrop(1) command. This arrangement even works while the Postfix mail system is not running. The local pickup(8) server picks up local submissions, enforces some sanity checks to protect Postfix, and gives the sender, recipients and message content to the cleanup(8) server.


Tracking the original sender
The pickup(8) knows the uid of the user dropped the message as well as the sender address that was used, which you can see from the logs:
postfix/pickup[1337]: 123456789A: uid=1000 from=<admin@example.com>

On a more verbose logging level you can see that the cleanup(8) adds the Received header containing the userid derived from this information:
postfix/cleanup[2828]: cleanup_header_callback: 
    'Received: by mail.example.com (Postfix, from userid 1000)
       ??id 123456789A; Sun, 26 Apr 2020 16:49:01 +0300 (EEST)'

Content filtering suggestion
The pickup(8) has content inspection controls including:
       content_filter (empty)
              After  the  message  is  queued,  send the entire message to the
              specified transport:destination.

The documentation for Postfix After-Queue Content Filter shows examples on adding custom content filters that handle unfiltered messages and puts them back to the queue. Similarly, you could write a content filter script that checks the user id from the Received header and compares it with the addresses the user is allowed to use. The implementation possibilities for the script as well as the lookup tables it uses are countless.
The mail flow could look like, e.g.,
Unfiltered -> pickup(8) -> cleanup(8) -> qmgr(8)    smtp(8)  -> Filtered
   from                                  Postfix --<
  sendmail                    ^          queue      local(8) -> Filtered
                              |            |
                            smtpd(8)       v
                            10027     <- script

Configuration draft
The configuration in the master.cf could have something like:
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
  -o content_filter=uidcheck:dummy

uidcheck  unix  -       n       n       -       10      pipe
    flags=Rq user=filter null_sender=
    argv=/path/to/uidcheck --nexthop localhost:10027 -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}

localhost:10027 inet  n       -       n       -       10      smtpd
  -o content_filter=
  -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,...
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  ...
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/uidcheck_map
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
  ...

Here uidcheck refers to the script and filter to the special user running it. That user should be protected as mentioned in the documentation:

Create a dedicated local user account called "filter". This user handles all potentially dangerous mail content - that is why it should be a separate account. Do not use "nobody", and most certainly do not use "root" or "postfix".

The last entry is an smtpd(8) instance that is used for injecting the mail back to the queue. It is just a brief example, and needs adjustments to your requirements. The example configuration parameters:

content_filter= clears the content filter. This prevents content filters configured in main.cf to be used again for the message that has already been processed.
likewise, the receive_override_options= should be configured to avoid duplicating work that was already done before the script

To prevent others from using this as a backdoor to bypass any other controls:

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable reminds you need SASL authentication for the filter script. (Please notice that this is an incomplete setup.)
smtpd_client_restrictions enforces the SASL authentication
=reject_sender_login_mismatch forbids other users that could use the SASL authentication for this smtpd instance, too, with the help of...
...hash:/etc/postfix/uidcheck_map, a special override map that allows the filter user to use any sender address from this domain.

As a hash:, it requires postmap /etc/postfix/uidcheck_map.
Content example:
@example.com  filter





